# How can I write C# Visual Studio F1 help that displays in a browser?

Tags: c#

I have an C# assembly with classes, methods and properties documented in the code, using the /// syntax before each member.  I would like to generate html help files from the documentation and place them on my website.  When a user implements the assembly and presses F1 on a class or property can it opened in a web browser?  This is just copying the function of any .NET Framework class.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at [Sandcastle](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/) which allows you to generate HTML documentation from XML comments in code source.